# High-level Java filesystem content manipulation : old style vs. jcr?

Tags: java, filesystems, jcr

what is the best way to choose for managing text/binary content on filesystem? Typically when building web applications with a lot of multimedia binaries and other various text based content stored on filesystem, JDK 6 java.io is still too much low level.

- It will change with java 7 as you can see [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/) thanks to new java.nio.file.* package

But until java 7 is out and implemented by IDEs etc., I really don't know what to use for this, except of org.apache.commons.io. I tried few samples with JackRabbit, but I'm not sure if it is a good idea for the purpose I mentioned at the beginning. Is it possible to manage all that filesystem binary/text content by JackRabbit ? Put it all into nodes and properties instead of directories. Does it bring advantages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're looking for, but Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) libraries have an io package, and in particular, a [Files](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) class full of static methods for file manipulation.

It's not a content repository system, but may provide enough functionality for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Great additional library to know about. I was partially asking whether the operations on ""multimedia binaries and other various text based content stored on filesystem""  could be done in JCR style with Apache Jackrabbit, or it's nonsense and it way better to stick with usual filesystem content manipulation.